# Unique & Rept Customer Sales based on date

Tags: mysql

I am new to Mysql, I have the data like this,

```
Order_dt    User_ID Sales
28-03-2022  PRPK-12 84
28-03-2022  PRPK-11 41
28-03-2022  PRPK-10 55
28-03-2022  PRPK-12 76
26-03-2022  PRPK-10 54
27-03-2022  PRPK-11 88
27-03-2022  PRPK-11 51
27-03-2022  PRPK-10 40 
27-03-2022  PRPK-10 40
```

& I need o/p like below the format.

```
Order_date  Unique_Cx   Unique_Cx_Sales Rept_Cx Rept_Cx_Sales
26-03-2022  1   54  0   0
27-03-2022  0   0   2   219
28-03-2022  2   96  1   160
```

I'm getting only unique & Rept count by using the 'Having' function, but im unable to map with the sales. Kindly help.
Thanking you.

Comment: How are the 2 unique the 28th?

Comment: The headings in your desired output are not meaningful can you explain in words how you get there. I am guessing unique_cs is distinct user_id but after that I don't see where the orther columns from are or how the data is derived,

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have reviewed my ques. I think its clear now. 
26-03-2022 - only 1 cx purchased.
27-03-2022 - 4 cxs but i need count distinct with their sum of total sales.

Comment: only 1 cx purchased. 27-03-2022 how so? PRPK-11 and PRPK-10 look like 2 with PRPK-10 also appearing on 26-03-2022?

Comment: I need output on day wise. If you consider on 27-03-2022, PRPK -11,PRPK-10 both purchased on same date twice. the distinct count of *User_ID* will be 2 on 27-03-2022. & sum of total sales on 27-03-2022 is 219.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First group by dt and user id in sub query then use conditional aggregation

```
select order_dt,
        sum(case when cd = 1 then 1 else 0 end) unique_cx,
        sum(case when cd = 1 then sales else 0 end) unique_cx_sales,
        sum(case when cd > 1 then 1 else 0 end) repeat_cx,
        sum(case when cd > 1 then sales else 0 end) repeat_cx_sales
from       
(
select   order_dt, user_id,
    count(*) cd,sum(sales) sales
from t
group by order_dt,user_id
) s
group by order_dt
;
```

Comment: P.Salmon very very thanks to you... query is working but i didn't understand Count(*), what does it mean??

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count